# MVC5 - JQuery plugin is not working

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-steps

> Thank you so much, I solved my problem. I changed my style of calling css and javascript files from the project files.

I have a MVC5 project, I want to use some plugins but it doesn't seem working. I started a blank project to see if the plugins are working and they work perfect there. In my project, there are no css-js.

This is what my form must have look like.

[image]

And this is what is actually look like right now.
[image]

And this is the code I wrote. It works in a blank project successfully.

```
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="header">
                <h2>BASIC EXAMPLE - HORIZONTAL LAYOUT</h2>
                <ul class="header-dropdown m-r--5">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Something else here</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <div id="wizard_horizontal">
                    <h2>First Step</h2>
                    <section>
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer ut nulla nunc. Maecenas
                            arcu sem, hendrerit a tempor quis, sagittis accumsan tellus. In hac habitasse platea
                            dictumst. Donec a semper dui. Nunc eget quam libero. Nam at felis metus. Nam tellus
                            dolor, tristique ac tempus nec, iaculis quis nisi.
                        </p>
                    </section>
                    <h2>Second Step</h2>
                    <section>
                        <p>
                            Donec mi sapien, hendrerit nec egestas a, rutrum vitae dolor. Nullam venenatis diam ac
                            ligula elementum pellentesque. In lobortis sollicitudin felis non eleifend. Morbi
                            tristique tellus est, sed tempor elit. Morbi varius, nulla quis condimentum dictum,
                            nisi elit condimentum magna, nec venenatis urna quam in nisi. Integer hendrerit sapien
                            a diam adipiscing consectetur. In euismod augue ullamcorper leo dignissim quis elementum
                            arcu porta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum leo
                            velit, blandit ac tempor nec, ultrices id diam. Donec metus lacus, rhoncus sagittis
                            iaculis nec, malesuada a diam. Donec non pulvinar urna. Aliquam id velit lacus.
                        </p>
                    </section>
                    <h2>Third Step</h2>
                    <section>
                        <p>
                            Morbi ornare tellus at elit ultrices id dignissim lorem elementum. Sed eget nisl at justo
                            condimentum dapibus. Fusce eros justo, pellentesque non euismod ac, rutrum sed quam.
                            Ut non mi tortor. Vestibulum eleifend varius ullamcorper. Aliquam erat volutpat.
                            Donec diam massa, porta vel dictum sit amet, iaculis ac massa. Sed elementum dui
                            commodo lectus sollicitudin in auctor mauris venenatis.
                        </p>
                    </section>
                    <h2>Forth Step</h2>
                    <section>
                        <p>
                            Quisque at sem turpis, id sagittis diam. Suspendisse malesuada eros posuere mauris vehicula
                            vulputate. Aliquam sed sem tortor. Quisque sed felis ut mauris feugiat iaculis nec
                            ac lectus. Sed consequat vestibulum purus, imperdiet varius est pellentesque vitae.
                            Suspendisse consequat cursus eros, vitae tempus enim euismod non. Nullam ut commodo
                            tortor.
                        </p>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="~/Contents/plugins/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Contents/plugins/jquery-steps/jquery.steps.js"></script>
```

Comment: @soilovecuu How can i understand if it is load correctly or not, and what should I do in that case? I checked the imported files thousands of times and there is no problem with them.

Comment: @soilovecuu I have never looked at it before. This is the error : Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

I fixed them but the same problem is still there.